# How to trigger a table to change the value of another table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, triggers

I've created three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Clients
(
    ClientID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    First_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
    ReservationID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientID INT FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES Clients(ClientID),
    Reservation_paid VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'NO',
)
CREATE TABLE Payment
(
    Payment_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientID INT FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES Clients(ClientID),
    ReservationID INT FOREIGN KEY (ReservationID) REFERENCES Reservation(ReservationID),
)
```

I would like to change the value of the column Reservation_paid to YES at the Reservation table whenever the Client does pay the reservation, and i want to do it automatically with trigger.

Example: If the `ClientID` at the Reservation table exists at the Payment table automatically the value of the Reservation_paid will set to YES.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Payment] 
FOR INSERT
AS
declare @ClientID int;
select @ClientID =i.ClientID from inserted i;   

if update(ClientID)
    UPDATE Reservation set Reservation_paid='Yes' WHERE  
    ClientID=@ClientID;

--PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
```

Answer (score 0):

*After Insert* Trigger should do something like this

```
UPDATE R 
SET    Reservation_paid = 'Yes' 
FROM   reservation R 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   INSERTED I 
               WHERE  I.clientid = R.clientid 
                      AND I.reservationid = R.reservationid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a trigger that will work on table `Reservation` after any `insert` or `update` on `ClientId` column of table `Payment`. Then match the `ClientID` with `ClientID` column of `Reservation` table and update the corresponding `Reservation_paid` to YES.

Edit: 
The trigger will be like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateReservation_paid` AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON `Payment`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 AS 
begin
 update Reservation 
 SET Reservation_paid='YES'
 Where NEW.ClientID = Reservation.ClientID 
       and NEW.ReservationID = Reservation.ReservationID   
end
```

Comment: Ive got errors at NEW.ClientID and NEW.ReservationID and it says 'The multi-part identifier 'NEW.ClientID/NEW.ReservationID' could not be found'.
And other errors at: after/or/on/each but i think those are because of the Sql syntax.

Comment: Try replacing `NEW` by `inserted` and removing `OR UPDATE` and let me know the result.

Comment: I'm using sql server and this didnt fixed the errors but ive already marked the right answer that did the job. Thank you.

Comment: Just for interest: What was the last output/Error message.

Comment: Sorry for delay, but i still get the same error. 'Incorrect syntax near After/On/row/begin' and the error for the replaced words you suggested.

Comment: Okay, I will see this later as you got a functional result already.

Comment: I see I forgot to write `AS` before `begin`.